Tag helper <partial /> in _layout.cshtml page for start up after website load
There are a lot of similar questions but not the one that give me the solution.
This is my attempt: I want to when the website loads show a alert Modal box with data coming from a model.
The site is a Blazor Server app.
This the model
public class AlertModal
{

    [Key]
    public int AlertId { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a requierd field")]
    public string TextPar { get; set; } 
    public string TextPar1 { get; set; }
    public string TextPar2 { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a requierd field")]
    public bool Show { get; set; }
}

This the PageModel of the partial page:
public class _InfoPartialModel : PageModel
{
    public AlertModal AlertModal { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        AlertModal = new AlertModal()
        {
            TextPar = "This is a test",
            Show = true
        };
    }
}

And this the partial view page


   @page
@model Tjoba.Pages.Shared._InfoPartialModel
@{
}

@if (Model.AlertModal.Show)
{
    <div class="modal fade " id="IndexModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title text-black">@Model.AlertModal.TextPar </h5>
                    <button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="/images/Vacation_volleyball.jpeg" class=" col-12 p-0 m-0 mx-auto " style="transform:none" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" value="1" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Sluiten</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#IndexModal").modal('show');
            }, 4000);           

        });
    </script>
}



And for startup in the _Layout.cshtml page:
<partial name="_InfoPartial" model="Model.AlertModal" />

I found the explanation of this here:
But when starting the website there comes a the following error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
RuntimeBinderException: 'Tjoba.Pages.Pages__Host' does not contain a definition for 'AlertModal'
The _Host.cshtml file:


@page "/"
@namespace Tjoba.Pages

@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers


@{
    Layout = "_Layout";

}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />



Question is, what as the _Host file to do with this?. I do what wrong but I can't find what it is.

Test Result

The structure of my test project

1. Data/AlertModal.cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BlazorApp2.Data
{
    public class AlertModal
    {
        [Key]
        public int AlertId { get; set; }
        public string? Image { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a required field")]
        public string? TextPar { get; set; }
        public string? TextPar1 { get; set; }
        public string? TextPar2 { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a required field")]
        public bool Show { get; set; }
    }

}

2. AlertModalComponent.cs
@page "/alert-modal"
@using BlazorApp2.Data
@inject AlertModalService AlertModalService

@code {
    private AlertModal AlertModal { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        AlertModal = AlertModalService.GetAlertModal();
    }
}

@if (AlertModal.Show)
{
    <div class="modal fade" id="IndexModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title text-black">@AlertModal.TextPar</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <img src="@AlertModal.Image" style="width:72px;height:50px" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">关闭</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('IndexModal'));
                modal.show();
            }, 4000);
        });
    </script>
}

3. _Host.cshtml
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazorApp2.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp2.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    

    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    @* Add this line *@
    <component type="typeof(AlertModalComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

4. AlertModalService.cs
using BlazorApp2.Data;

namespace BlazorApp2
{
    public class AlertModalService
    {
        public AlertModal GetAlertModal()
        {
            return new AlertModal()
            {
                TextPar = "This is a test",
                Show = true,
                Image = "/images/test.png"
            };
        }
    }

}


Hi Jason, Thank you so much for make a test app for me, because it was for me looking for a needle in the haystack.

It works perfectly fine, but now when I navigate to another page then the modal also starts again. How to prevent it starts only ones at starting of the website

To achieve your goal of displaying a modal box on startup in a Blazor Server app, you can use a combination of Blazor components and Razor views. Given your current setup, it seems you are trying to mix Blazor components and Razor pages. Here's a refined approach:

Create a Blazor Component for the Modal: Create a new Blazor
component for the modal. This component will handle the display
logic for the modal box.
Add the Modal Component to the Main Layout: Incorporate the modal
component into the _Layout.cshtml page to ensure it loads on
startup.


Thanks. Khach for pointing me to the right direction.
